# Non-trivial responsive design layout techniques (i.e., moving things around)

Tags: css, layout, responsive-design

It's a simple feat to clear a column in skinny viewports, but I need techniques for moving things around. I'm trying to reconcile a pair of mobile and desktop mocks that differ dramatically. The desktop mock contains a 3-column grid that is supposed to collapse into a one-column grid in the mobile view, which then hides some elements and reflows others.

Hiding elements is trivial with `display: none`. The hard part for me is breaking elements out of the columns and moving them around all over the place, much like http://bostonglobe.com/. From Firebugging their layout, I have found that you can subvert source order by manipulating float, which might be reset and have the element cleared with a media query in a mobile viewport. This is one way to make a middle column (in a 3-column grid) clear underneath the contents of the other 2 columns in a collapsed view.

Is this the extent of what can be done with pure CSS to reflow layouts responsively? Are there other techniques (perhaps using JavaScript) I can use?

Comment: Can you tell us more about your exact desired behaviours? It's difficult to point to CSS techniques without specific designs in mind.

Answer (score 2):

You can't manipulate the DOM to that extent...there is no way of actually re-ordering markup. The way I work round this is by duplicating the element and positioning it where it needs to be for the specific viewport width and hiding it until it's needed.

The best way to avoid this altogether is to design mobile first:

http://stuffandnonsense.co.uk/projects/320andup/

Comment: You actually can reflow the order of adjacent containers if the first container is floated right. The problem is that this technique is very limited to working only with directly adjacent containers.

Comment: Very true, although I think the OP recognises that. There are plugins out there which offer a more automated approach, e.g. http://isotope.metafizzy.co/ (jQuery plugin).

Answer (score 0):

I think the float example is the limits of what can be done with pure CSS but with javascript you can do virtually anything - jQuery .append can be used to pull out any element and put it somewhere else; effectively changing the order and layout of the DOM.

http://api.jquery.com/append/

But from a performance standpoint, .append isn't cheap so I'd try to avoid it if you can by "building mobile/small first". And another way to achieve it is to actually have different layouts for different screen widths and then use media queries (not just CSS to hide things, but actually in the javascript so the "hidden" content actually isn't rendered or included in the code at all until it's needed, so the DOM isn't crowded with un-used/hidden elements or unnecessary code).

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 3.0 has [column re-ordering](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering) :) This means that you can specify the column ordering separately for each media queries purely using pre-set CSS class names, no javascript or any funky hacks!

Sample from Bootstrap docs:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-9 col-md-push-3">Appears first in code, second in browser</div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-md-pull-9">Appears second in code, first in browser</div>
</div>
```